# How do I make an effect on a list of radio buttons (when one is checked) apply to each one individually not all of them?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

What I am trying to do is have the user click on any number throughout a rating scale (with each number as a radio button) and have the background color of the design around that number only. However, as I demonstrate below, when the user clicks on the #1 for example, it changes the background color of every radiobutton in the scale. How can I apply it to each individual one?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>

        body{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            background-color: bisque;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .head{
            text-align: center;
            transform: translate(20px, 150px);
            }

        .rating{
            transform: translate(320px, 200px);   
        }

        .rating label{
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 30px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .rating input{
                display: none;
            }

        .labels{
            display: flex;
            list-style: none; 
        }

        input#rate1:checked ~ label{
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .bottom{
            transform: translate(300px, 150px);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="head">
            <h1>On a Scale From 0-10, How Are You Feeling?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="labels">
            <ul>
                <li>Rock Bottom</li>
                <li>Terrible</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="rating">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate0"><label for="rate0"
            >0</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate1"><label for="rate1"
            >1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate2"><label for="rate2"
            >2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate3"><label for="rate3"
            >3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate4"><label for="rate4"
            >4</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate5"><label for="rate5"
            >5</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate6"><label for="rate6"
            >6</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate7"><label for="rate7"
            >7</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate8"><label for="rate8"
            >8</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate9"><label for="rate9"
            >9</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate10"><label for="rate10"
            >10</label>

            <div class="bottom">
                <a href="index.html"><button class="btn1">Next</button></a> 
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello. You have been given the answers to your question. Please take as solved any of the provided answers that helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this rule:

```
input#rate1:checked ~ label{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

This way you are referring to all the tags `label`. But you only need to refer to the current one, so you need to add the corresponding attribute, like this:

```
input#rate1:checked ~ label[for="rate1"]{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Was it necessary?

```css
body{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            background-color: bisque;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .head{
            text-align: center;
            transform: translate(20px, 150px);
            }

        .rating{
            transform: translate(320px, 200px);   
        }

        .rating label{
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 30px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            background-color: white;
        }
       
        .rating input{
                display: none;
            }

        .labels{
            display: flex;
            list-style: none; 
        }
        
        input#rate0:checked ~ label[for="rate0"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }

        input#rate1:checked ~ label[for="rate1"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
         input#rate2:checked ~ label[for="rate2"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
        input#rate3:checked ~ label[for="rate3"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
         input#rate4:checked ~ label[for="rate4"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
        input#rate5:checked ~ label[for="rate5"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
         input#rate6:checked ~ label[for="rate6"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
        input#rate7:checked ~ label[for="rate7"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
         input#rate8:checked ~ label[for="rate8"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
        input#rate9:checked ~ label[for="rate9"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
         input#rate10:checked ~ label[for="rate10"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        
        


        .bottom{
            transform: translate(300px, 150px);
        }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="head">
            <h1>On a Scale From 0-10, How Are You Feeling?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="labels">
            <ul>
                <li>Rock Bottom</li>
                <li>Terrible</li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="rating">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate0"><label for="rate0"
            >0</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate1"><label for="rate1"
            >1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate2"><label for="rate2"
            >2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate3"><label for="rate3"
            >3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate4"><label for="rate4"
            >4</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate5"><label for="rate5"
            >5</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate6"><label for="rate6"
            >6</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate7"><label for="rate7"
            >7</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate8"><label for="rate8"
            >8</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate9"><label for="rate9"
            >9</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate10"><label for="rate10"
            >10</label>

            <div class="bottom">
                <a href="index.html"><button class="btn1">Next</button></a> 
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what  user `surgey kuznetsov` stated :- the `~`.

Just a + can solve the issue and make it terribly small. It selects only the next adjacent sibling. No need for adding several lines of css and markup - three lines do it all-

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: bisque;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.head{
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(20px, 150px);
  }

.rating{
  transform: translate(320px, 200px);   
}

.rating label{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.rating input{
      display: none;
  }

.labels{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none; 
}

input:checked + label{
  background-color: blue;
}

.bottom{
  transform: translate(300px, 150px);
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
    <h1>On a Scale From 0-10, How Are You Feeling?</h1>
</div>
<div class="labels">
    <ul>
        <li>Rock Bottom</li>
        <li>Terrible</li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate0"><label for="rate0"
    >0</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate1"><label for="rate1"
    >1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate2"><label for="rate2"
    >2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate3"><label for="rate3"
    >3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate4"><label for="rate4"
    >4</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate5"><label for="rate5"
    >5</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate6"><label for="rate6"
    >6</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate7"><label for="rate7"
    >7</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate8"><label for="rate8"
    >8</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate9"><label for="rate9"
    >9</label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate10"><label for="rate10"
    >10</label>

    <div class="bottom">
        <a href="index.html"><button class="btn1">Next</button></a> 
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this tips to design your radio whatever what you want :
it's to make one element  of each  radio in the behind of radio,
and  each appearance of radio makes none  then you can add your style in these elements that shown and the click is on the radio that one ,so i just make  here  clean your code and give you a solution based on what i understood :

```
#CSS

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: bisque;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80vh;
}

.rating label {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input:checked+label {
    background-color: rgb(255, 233, 40);
}
/////

#HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styleeee.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <body>
        <div class="labels">
            <ul>
                <li>Rock Bottom</li>
                <li>Terrible</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="head">
            <h1>On a Scale From 0-10, How Are You Feeling?</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="rating">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate0"><label for="rate0">0</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate1"><label for="rate1">1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate2"><label for="rate2">2</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate3"><label for="rate3">3</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate4"><label for="rate4">4</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate5"><label for="rate5">5</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate6"><label for="rate6">6</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate7"><label for="rate7">7</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate8"><label for="rate8">8</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate9"><label for="rate9">9</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rate10"><label for="rate10">10</label>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <a href="index.html"><button class="btn1">Next</button></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>

</html>
```